# How to create dynamic , customized button?

Tags: android-layout

I try to create dynamic button, it creating but I want customized , color , size and touch event color.Can you tell how I create.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code

```
Button b = new Button(this);
             b.setText("Dynamic Button");
             b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
```

LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Folow this tutorial [Customize Button](http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/customize-button-in-android/)